# Error Bibliography on Lyx

Tags: lyx, natbib

I am trying to run the Bibtex bibliography in Lyx as can be seen in the below image the Add bibliography TOC is disabled

[image]

Also I have still continued with adding the saved bibtex bibliography however when running the program the below prompted is being shown

[image]

Anyone have an idea why is this happening?

I have used the `\usepackage{natbib}`

Below is step by step of how i am getting to the above error:

Enter citation in JabRef

[image]

Go to lyx and click on 'insert - List/TOC - Biblatext Bibliography'

Enter the citation as per image 1 above and then go to "Insert Citation" and add the citation as per below:

[image]

Once I click on the view icon the error is prompted

Comment: Try not to use non-ASCII chars in the key of a bibliography entry. I.e. write `morosargio2018fiho`

Comment: @moewe - I entered this but from the bibtex so where do I add the above mentioned?

Comment: In your `.bib` file you will have something like `@book{Morosagio2018FIHO, author = {...} ...}` make sure that the bit after `@book` does not contain non-ASCII chars.

Comment: I don't have any ASCII chars and still it is not working

Comment: Mhhh, sorry I would need to know more about what you are doing and the error you get. Unfortunately I don't know a lot about LyX, so I can't really help you.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: @scottkosty - I have added a further detail in the above maybe it will help more